# C exercise with malloc and realloc in a function

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, realloc

I have this excercise:

Write a C function RandArr2() that takes as parameters three values:

- an array of integers A
- an integer n representing the size (number of elements) of A
- an integer n’

The function RandArr2() returns an array as follows:

- if n == n’, it returns A
- if n > n’, it reallocs the array A, creating a new array of integers A’ of size n’
- if n < n’, it reallocs the array A, creating a new array of integers A’ of size n’; it also fills
  all the positions of A’ between n and n’ with random integers between -10 and 10.

This is my implementation that return a Segmentation faults.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int * RandArr2(int * A, int n, int n1) {
  int i;
  if (n == n1) {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      A[i] = rand();
    }
    return A;

  } else if (n < n1) {
    //reallocs the array A, creating a new array of integers A’ of size n’
    A1 = (int * ) realloc(A, n1 * sizeof(int));
    return A1;
  } else {
    /*reallocs the array A, creting a new array of integers A’ of size n’; it also fills all the
    positions of A’ between n and n’ with random integers between -10 and 10 */
    A1 = (int * ) realloc(A, n1 * sizeof(int));
    for (i = n; i < n1; i++) {
      A1[i] = -10 + rand() % (-10 - 10 + 1);
    }
    return A1;
  }
}

int main() {
  int n, n1;
  int * A;
  int i;
  printf("insert two integer:");
  scanf("%d, %d", & n, & n1);
  A = (int * ) malloc(n * sizeof(int)); //inizializzo l'array
  if (A != NULL) {
    A = RandArr2(A, n, n1);
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
      printf("\n Elemento del vettore: %d", A[i]);
    }
    free(A);
  } else {
    printf("Error!");
    exit(0);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I'm new in C, so you're welcome for every kind of help.

Comment: Your `n<n1` and `n>n1` cases are mixed up.  Also, you should populate `A` *before* calling `RandArr2`.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed some issues related to segmentation fault in your program. I have removed the `rand()` function to make things more clear. You can add `rand()` wherever you want to add as per your requirements.

The main issue was however, in the `for` loop in the `main()` you are printing the contents of the returned array. I have fixed it. Please check the `test-expression` in the `for` loop in `main()` for understanding the issue. The index of the array cannot be more than `array_size-1` as index for array starts from `0`.

**The fixed code is below.**

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int* RandArr2(int* A, int n, int n1) {
    int i;
    int* A1 = NULL;
    if (n == n1) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            A[i] = 0xDEAD;
        }
        return A;

    }
    else if (n > n1) {
        //reallocs the array A, creating a new array of integers A’ of size n’
        A1 = (int*)realloc(A, n1 * sizeof(int));
        return A1;
    }
    else {
        /*reallocs the array A, creting a new array of integers A’ of size n’; it also fills all the
        positions of A’ between n and n’ with random integers between -10 and 10 */
        A1 = (int*)realloc(A, n1 * sizeof(int));
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            A[i] = 0xDEAD;
        }
        for (i = n; i < n1; i++) {
            A1[i] = 0xBEAD;
        }
        return A1;
    }
}
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
int main() {
    int n, n1;
    int* A;
    int i;
    printf("insert two integer:");
    scanf_s("%d, %d", &n, &n1);
    A = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int)); //inizializzo l'array
    if (A != NULL) {
        A = RandArr2(A, n, n1);
        for (i = 0; i < ((n > n1) ? n1 : n); i++) {
            printf("\n Elemento del vettore: 0x%x", A[i]);
        }
        free(A);
    }
    else {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here in the print for loop you had write  ((n > n1) ? n1 : n); this is because I don't know if my returned array will have n or n1 as size. It is correct? I have never seen this sintax

Comment: This is just a ternary operator. The idea here is to run for loop only till the last index of the allocated array.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for aswering. Now the code runs but I think that the realloc doesn't work :/